# Likelihood involving very small numbers

Tags: python, numpy, data-fitting, underflow

I have a large vector of likelihoods all in the range (0 to 1) but all numbers are quite a bit less than 1. I need to compute the maximum likelihood of the product of these vectors.

How can I avoid underflow, my fitter is failing in all my attempts. The first step I took was to divide my array by the max value in my array.
I am maximizing the product of the sum of two probabilities sampled n times,  Ultimately I need to minimize as per the BIC:

```
BIC = -2. * ln(L) + 5n_theta(nz)
```

Anyways `L` is an array of really small numbers of the form

```
L = product of ([(p(z1|a) + p(z1|b)), (p(z2|a) + p(z2|b)), ...., (p(zn|a) + p(zn|b))])
```

Here is an example with two parameters `a` and `b` that I vary and the array has size `n` and each `p` is `< 1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered working in log-likelihood?

`L = (p1 * p2 * p3) ** N` becomes `ln(L) = N * (ln(p1) + ln(p2) + ln(p3))`
Which will be much more resistant to numerical precision problems.

And then you can directly use `ln(L)` in your `-2.0 * ln(L) + 5n_theta(nz)`

Comment: Hello, I realized how poorly I had explained my question and I have largely edited it.

Comment: I have tried something similar but I believe I may have implemented it incorrectly, thanks for your help I will review